# dynamodb update denormalized data and keep consistency

Tags: python, database, amazon-dynamodb, consistency

I am using dynamodb with python API and denormalize my data in order to keep the reads fast. The think is that I am worried about keeping the consistency when updating my data say i have a table of users, each has a key and a name, and a table of purchases each has a key and a data containing buyer key (user) and the buyer's name.

I would like to update the user's name and update all his purchases using an atomic operation, like available in firebase (multi path update) explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1n9Kw3AORw&index=7&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: dynamodb now support transactional capabilities https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/

Comment: Will that solve my problem? how? can you post an answer?

Comment: @bestwishes can you post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice documentation of [dynamodb transaction](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/).

Here are few highlights of the blog post.

1. Dynamodb supports transaction capability `across multiple table` where you `can also have pre-condition on every insert` (i.e. insert into order table only if prev_snapshot=1223232, this will make sure you are modifying the last read data only.)
2. There are 2 types of gets supported TransactGetItems and Eventual/Strongly consistent GetItem. In `TransactGetItems, if a transaction is in progress the request is rejected`. while in the other 2 cases last committed data is returned based on your consistency requirements.
3. Transactions are not locks if some other thread is writing to a table without transaction, and if write succeeds before transaction is completed, and exception will be thrown on transaction.
4. No extra steps/permissions are required to enable transaction on a single region table.
5. Cost will double for every read and write whiles using transactional capabilities.

Here are the features which are not supported

1. `Transactional capabilities in global table`. but this can be avoided by request stickiness and should not be a big issue IMO.